# MariaDB bound to 0.0.0.0, but doesn't appear to be listening to all IPs?

Tags: mariadb, network, remote

My MariaDB server accepts connections at port `43210` without problems on the public IP address of, we'll say, `123.123.123.123` on `eth0`. This is on an Ubuntu 18.04 server that also has `192.168.1.10` configured for `eth0`.

I have a user configured to with permissions for all hosts (`%`):

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| myuser           | %         |
...
```

From a remote server (another host that is on the same LAN) I can connect to the public IP address of this MariaDB server:

```
$ mysql --user=myuser -pMYPASSWORD --host=123.123.123.123 --port=43210 mydatabase
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 340
Server version: 10.2.31-MariaDB-1:10.2.31+maria~bionic-log mariadb.org binary distribution
...
```

However, the problem is that when I try to connect to the LAN IP address, `mysql` times out:

```
$ mysql --user=myuser -pMYPASSWORD --host=192.168.1.10 --port=43210 mydatabase
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.10' (110 "Connection timed out")
```

Just to verify, `netstat -tlpn | grep mysql` shows it is listening on `0.0.0.0` which should be listening on all interfaces (I believe including the local IP):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43210           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      964/mysqld
```

I also run PostgreSQL on this same server with MariaDB and if I connect remotely from the same other test host from which I'm trying to make the mysql connection, it connects without a problem:

```
$ pg_isready -d mydb -h 192.168.1.10 -p 43211 -U myuser
192.168.1.10:43211 - accepting connections
```

The point of the last note about PGSQL is that I just want to clarify that connections are able to get through to the actual Linux server itself, just not MariaDB.

I have also disabled the `UFW` firewall temporarily in order to keep that out of the equation.

***What could be going wrong here?  What can I test further to isolate the problem?***

I suspect that perhaps the `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` may be the problem, but I thought that the quadruple 0 was in fact able to handle this.

Comment: This could be a firewall issue. Could you update your question to include the output of `sudo ufw status`? This will show whether you allow 43211 from one source but not the other.

Comment: Sorry, I turned off `ufw` as a temporary troubleshooting option before everything else and so it is disabled for troubleshooting @matigo.

Comment: Is your mysql server on a EC2 server? And does it have a policy to accept connections over 0.0.0.0:43210 ? What happens when you traceroute to 123.123.123.123 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue!

It turns out that it was a bug in the local private IP assignment with Ubuntu 18.04 and the host provider, Linode. After looking into things a little deeper, even though the private IP was assigned, manually setting up Netplan instead of the pre-existing automated networking setup resolved the communications issue.

Comment: oh was that it? glad you articulated the solution clearly for other people. you should upvote yourself.